# How to apply multiple classes to components on React 5?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Before v5, I was able to apply multiple class to the component like the following:

```js
import React from "react";

import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  image: {
    borderRadius: "50%",
    width: 256,
    height: 256,
  },
  shadow: {
    boxShadow: "-4px -3px 45px 21px rgba(0,0,0,0.35)",
  },
}));

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <img src={data.image} className={`${classes.image} ${classes.shadow}`} alt={data.title} />
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

However, since the change of styling engine(?), it seems like I can only apply a single styling like:

```js
import React from "react";

import { styled } from "@mui/system";

const ProfileImage = styled("img")({
    borderRadius: "50%",
    width: 256,
    height: 256,
});

const MyComponent= (props) => {
    const { data } = props;

    return (
        <ProfileImage src={data.image} alt={data.title} />
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Would there be any possible solution to achieve the same behavior as the one above?

Thank you!

Comment: just curious on what is the use of it, at the end all are merged together isn't it ... for readability ?

Comment: You can use [tss-react](https://www.tss-react.dev/) in order to use similar syntax as the v4 `makeStyles` but using styling engine (Emotion) of MUI v5.

Comment: @KcH : readability would be the one reason, but the main purpose is to dynamically apply the class depending on the condition, I'd say. I ain't sure if there is another way to achieve this tho :p

Comment: @RyanCogswell : awesome, I'll have a look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object and just spread the properties you want to use

```
const classes = {
  image: {
    borderRadius: "50%",
    width: 256,
    height: 256
  },
  shadow: {
    boxShadow: "-4px -3px 45px 21px rgba(0,0,0,0.35)"
  }
};

const ProfileImage1 = styled("img")({
  ...classes.image,
  ...classes.shadow
});
```

If you are using JS and want to benefit from type intellisense, you could use type annotation to get the hint of CSS properties

```
import { styled, SxProps, Theme } from "@mui/system";

/** @type{Record<string, SxProps<Theme>>} */
const classes = {
  image: {
    borderRadius: "50%",
    width: 256,
    height: 256
  },
  shadow: {
    boxShadow: "-4px -3px 45px 21px rgba(0,0,0,0.35)"
  }
};
```

Also, if you want to make the class conditional, styled component allows you to use prop from the component

```
const ProfileImage1 = styled("img")(({ shadow }) => ({
  ...classes.image,
  ...(shadow ? classes.shadow : {})
}));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "flex-start",
        gap: 5
      }}
    >
      <ProfileImage1 src={"https://via.placeholder.com/256"} shadow />
      <ProfileImage1 src={"https://via.placeholder.com/256"} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit condescending-feynman-clrqyd]

Comment: Thank you for the input! The question is would it be possible to add or remove the class depending on conditions? (e.g. add classA & remove classB on condition A)

Comment: btw, thank you for that type annotation tip! That helped soooooooooo much!

Comment: @Pogeun yes, `styled` component allows you to use the component prop. I updated my answer

Comment: it seems like my comment is removed for some reason D: Thank you so much for your help!!